# Sending data from a Javascript program to a Python program and vice versa

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

I'm working on a project where data gathered from a Javascript program can be treated in a python program since many libraries in python are absent in Javascript. I'm currently trying to use Ajax to send the data between the .js file and the .py file

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/Users/ryancheng/Desktop/coding/dashathon2021/dasha-app/webscrape.py",
      data: {param:restResult.data.features},
      success: function(response){
        output = response;
        alert(output);
      }
    }).done(function(data){
      console.log(data);
      alert(data);
    })
```

However I get the error `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. Any help would be much appreciated. If there is any other method to send files back and forth that I am not aware of, please let me know.

Comment: This is jQuery, did you import the jQuery script? You can use this: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Is your Python program running under a web server? Is your JavaScript program running on a web page or using [node](https://nodejs.org/en/)?

Comment: Please answer the comments as it will change the answer we give

Comment: I added it, but I don't think I imported the script correctly (I just pasted it a line above the ajax function). Is it true that you can't use jQuery with Node.js? I did it previously and I got the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

Comment: It is using node but I'm not sure what to do